# How can I receive Api data with url that changes?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, modal-dialog

I'm going to get an api from the id of the post I clicked on and make a modal in react-hooks
I want the last part of url to have id in it.

let url = `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${id}` <- This part!!

I know how to bring an id using Params. But shouldn't that be added to Router I'm not creating a new page, I'm creating a modal. Modal comes up when I click on a post on the main page. Isn't this different from the Route function to the new address?

How can I get API according to clicked id?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const { id } = useParams();
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    let url = `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${id}`;
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data.drinks);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    console.log(data);
  }, [id]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to look into are route/path/url parameters. Although I am not a react expert, a quick Google search does wonders for this.

Some links that might provide you the answer you are looking for: [a react router guide](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start), [a medium article](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-pass-multiple-route-parameters-in-a-react-url-path-4b919de0abbe#:%7E:text=Route%20params%20are%20parameters%20whose,data%20based%20on%20the%20parameter.), [a code example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params)

If the problem is that you need to send a request to the API based on where you click, then you can best associate the modals where you click on with an id of something that it belongs to. Then when you click on it, you can retrieve the full information from that thing from the backend using the associated id.